# AWS Athena Flatten Nested Column Without Losing Null Rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am using AWS Athena to query Jira data output as JSON in S3. Our data has a custom field that holds an array of applications affected by a bug. What I want to do is to create one row for affected application, while still keeping any issues that have no affected applications listed.

## My Data

```
{
    "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
    "id": "982832",
    "self": "https://reallycoolcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/982832",
    "key": "HI-1",
    "fields": {
        "summary": "Customer Care unresponsive on Web01",
        "customfield_14402": null
    }
}
{
    "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
    "id": "332422",
    "self": "https://reallycoolcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/332422",
    "key": "HI-2",
    "fields": {
        "summary": "RCC API issue - clients were experiencing a failure when navigating through the site.",
        "customfield_14402": null
    }
}
{
    "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
    "id": "114128",
    "self": "https://reallycoolcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/114128",
    "key": "HI-3",
    "fields": {
        "summary": "HIE customer can't connect",
        "customfield_14402": [
            {
                "self": "https://reallycoolcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14724",
                "value": "ECC",
                "id": "14724"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
    "id": "723392",
    "self": "https://reallycoolcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/723392",
    "key": "HI-4",
    "fields": {
        "summary": "Database Lock-Up Following Roll",
        "customfield_14402": [
            {
                "self": "https://reallycoolcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14722",
                "value": "CC",
                "id": "14722"
            },
            {
                "self": "https://reallycoolcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14724",
                "value": "ECC",
                "id": "14724"
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

## Desired Output

I want a query that can be used in Athena that would return five rows like below:

```
|-----------|--------------------------|
|    key    |     Affected App         |
|-----------|--------------------------|
| HI-1      | null                     |
|-----------|--------------------------|
| HI-2      | null                     |
|-----------|--------------------------|
| HI-3      | ECC                      |
|-----------|--------------------------|
| HI-4      | ECC                      |
|-----------|--------------------------|
| HI-4      | CC                       |
|-----------|--------------------------|
```

## What I've Tried So Far

I'm able to get one row per affected application (customfield_14402) with the following query (found solution [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html)):

```
SELECT key,affected_apps.value as affected_apps        
FROM jira_quicksight_poc
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(fields.customField_14402) as t(affected_apps)
```

However, this then excludes my two issues without any affected applications.

I'm able to work around this by creating a view out of the first query, then joining to it in another query like so:

```
SELECT aa.affected_apps, count(*) as num_issues
FROM jira_quicksight_poc AS m
LEFT JOIN affected_applications as aa
on aa.key = m.key
GROUP BY aa.affected_apps
ORDER BY num_issues DESC
```

However, this causes my data in S3 to be scanned twice. Trying to avoid that since it would effectively double our fees for this query via Athena pricing.

**Is there a way to get my desired outcome with a single query/scan of the data?**